# How to get route object from url string in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is there a way that if I have a string URL to get which route matches this URL ?
For example if I read the `href` from an anchor `<a href="/x/y/123">` can I get the route that matches this URL ? let's say the route's path is: `/x/y/:id`.

**Clarification:**
I need to build a directive that reads the value of `href` and somehow knows the route that this links match with so I can read some properties from that route to take a decision e.g:

```
<a href="/x/y/123" isAllowed>Go to</a>
```

I know I can get the `UrlTree` from the string, but don't know how to do the matching with the list of routes that I built.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    {path : 'inbox', component : InboxComponent, canActivate: [GetInService]} ,
    {path : 'inbox/:do/:id', component : InboxComponent, canActivate: [GetInService]} ,
```

[Routing tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)